# proportional html buttons using css?

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout, mobile

How can I have html buttons proportional to screen size?

I am trying to code an android app using html and css, with buttons that produce certain results, and the program runs fine. the only problem is, when I send my friend the file, his buttons are so small that it's difficult to use.

he's gotten tired of me sending him files to try, so can someone please give me the css that makes everything proportional to all screen sizes?

for example, there are three buttons in one row, I want it to look like the same layout, but larger on larger screens, and smaller on smaller screens.thanks.

I probably should have mentioned this, but the px I changed was in the font size located in the body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use percents** to define specific button proportions.

```
.button {
   height:10%;
   width:10%;
}
```

**Would get you a more accurate and preferred result than:**

```
.button {
   height:100px;
   width:100px;
}
```

The only reason you would get different on different browser sizes is if you defined the button sizes as **specific pixel sizes**.

Comment: how would I do that? like everything I need to do for that to work?

Comment: Change the values from percent to pixels and it will take up that % value of how big the div is. Let's say you had a header that took up 20% of the page, and you wanted a button which took up 80% of the header height, then you would put the button inside of the div header ( naturally ) and Mark the height as 80% using CSS.

Comment: You could help others find the answer to this question by marking as this as the correct answer. Thank you.